# Compactness of a nonlinear operator

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, differential-equations, differential-operators, compactness

Let $H^{1}_{0}(0;\pi)=\{f\in L^{2}(0; \pi): f^{\prime}\in L^{2}(0; \pi)\ \text{and}\  f(0)=f(\pi)=0 \} .$ equipped with the following norm $$\|f\|=\Big(\int_{0}^{\pi}|f'(x)|^2dx \Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$
for $f\in H^{1}_{0}(0;\pi).$

Consider the operator $K:C([0,a],H^{1}_{0}(0;\pi))\longrightarrow H^{1}_{0}(0;\pi)$ by:
$$K(f)(x)=\int_{0}^{\pi}\beta(x,y)\sin(f^{\prime}(t_0)(y))dy\quad \text{for}\ f\in C([0,a],H^{1}_{0}(0;\pi))$$
where $a>0$, $t_0\in [0,a]$ and  $\beta$ is $C^{1}$-function on $[0,\pi]\times[0,\pi]$.
I am in the step to construct a compact operator, so I found the operator $K$. In order to prove the compactness of $K$, i used the the following Kolmogorov theorem;

Theorem: A subset $F$ in $L^{p}(a, b ; X)$ is relatively compact if and only if:

1. $F$ is $p$-equiintegrable; that is, $$
       \lim _{h \downarrow 0} \int_{a}^{b-h}\|f(t+h)-f(t)\|^{p} d t=0,
       $$
   uniformly for $f \in F$.
2. For each interval $[\alpha, \beta]$ included in $[a, b]$, the set
   $$
   \left\{\int_{\alpha}^{\beta} f(t) d t ; f \in F\right\}
   $$
   is relatively compact in $X$.

I am not sure if my attempt is correct. Any remarks?

Comment: Even if your operator is nonlinear, what topology do you use on $H_0^1$? And $f \in L^2(0,\pi)$ together with $f(0) = f(\pi) = 0$ doesn't make much sense to me. Do you mean $f \in C(0,\pi)$?

Comment: Thank you sir for the reply. $H_0^1$ is equipped with following norm $$\|u\|=\Big(\int_{0}^{\pi}|u^{\prime}(x)|^2dx\Big)^{\frac{1}{2}}.$$ For your remark i meant $f\in L^2(0,\pi).$

Comment: could you be more explicit sir about your remark?

Comment: I don't see the point of having a time dependence on $f$: your operator depends only on the value at one fixed time $t_0$. Also: what do you mean by $f'$? Is this a time or a space or a both derivative?

Comment: Actually  i am studying a nonlocal differential equation. The situation imposes that the operator depends on the value at one fixed time. $f'$ means a space derivative.